# react split panel resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to create dynamically resized panels with react and foundation. I have tried react-split-pane and other similar libraries, but they are messing with the responsiveness of the page. I also tried the resize css3 property but it is not flexible as it only allows the containers to be resized only to the right and bottom and I was unable to style the resize handle to be a horizontal or vertical bar.

Any suggestion would help.

Comment: I've been playing around w/ this for my own project but haven't landed at a good solution yet. i've been trying to use the `onDrag` event with `draggable={true}` set on a handle on the border of my component. When the `onDrag` event fires, the callback receives an `event` object with a `clientY` prop (or `clientX`) that indicates its new position.  In my handler function, I diffed the new `clientY` from the old `clientY` to determine the direction user was moving mouse. then `this.setState({panelSize: this.state.panelSize + increment})`. My panel's height was set to `this.state.panelSize`.

Comment: [...cont] unfortunately this method is a little computationally intensive, so it didn't go smoothly, but maybe by adjusting the size `increment` or `debounce`ing the update function could smooth it out.  Anyway, I'll post here if I get further, but wanted to share approach in case this is still on your to-do list.

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible with `react-resizeable` once [pull request 76](https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable/pull/76) gets handled.

For now, you can grab the code from [the fork](https://github.com/RaoHai/react-resizable/tree/feat-vertical-and-horizontal-resize-handle).