# How to make bootstrap table columns resizable using react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to make columns resizable using react

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please try and share where you got stuck, not just asking someone to solve you problem from scratch.

Comment: I want to know how to start

Comment: @PratikN, it has been awhile, I'm not sure if you are still interested in doing this. If not,feel free to close this. If so, does this have to involve bootstrap (I might have a React solution)?

Comment: For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49804104/1739000

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//$("td,th")
$("td:first-child,td:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(3)")
  .css({
    /* required to allow resizer embedding */
    position: "relative"
  })
  /* check .resizer CSS */
  .prepend("<div class='resizer'></div>")
  .resizable({
    resizeHeight: false,
    // we use the column as handle and filter
    // by the contained .resizer element
    handleSelector: "",
    onDragStart: function(e, $el, opt) {
      // only drag resizer
      if (!$(e.target).hasClass("resizer"))
        return false;
      return true;
    }
  });
  });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 800px;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

th {
  color: white;
  background: #535353;
}

pre {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/*
   this is important!
   make sure you define this here
   or in jQuery codef
*/
.resizer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  width: 16px;    
  cursor: col-resize;       
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">

  <h1>
            jquery-resizable - Table Column Resizing
        </h1>
  <hr />
  <p>
    This example makes the first two columns of the table resizable.
  </p>

  <hr />

  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>
        col 1
      </th>
      <th>
        col 2
      </th>
      <th>
        col 3
      </th>
      <th>
        col 4
      </th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Column 1
        </td>
        <td>

          Column 2
        </td>
        <td>

          Column 3
        </td>
        <td>
          Column 4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Column 1
        </td>
        <td>
          Column 2
        </td>
        <td>
          Column 3
        </td>
        <td>
          Column 4
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <hr />
  <p>
    To create resizable columns requires a bit of extra effort as tables don't have an easy way to create a drag handle that can be moved around.
  </p>
  <p>
    To make columns resizable, we can add an element to the right of the column to provide the handle so we have a visual indicator for dragging. The table cell to resize is made <code>position:relative</code> and the injected element is <code>position: absolute</code>    and pushed to the right of the cell to provide the drag handle. Dragging then simply resizes the cell.
  </p>
  <p>
    In practice this means you need some CSS (or jquery styling) to force the injected styling and the logic to inject the element.
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. but i want to use react not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Resizable Column for react-bootstrap

Please see the code spinnet [Code sandbox Resizable columns](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-resizable-column-znqj8)

uses 'column-resizer' npm package

Comment: You can paste your code in your answer (it's not that big :)